# How to Get current date and create directory Everyday in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

get current date and make directory and second when directory is created, in that directory I have to store excel file and also save file as current date.

```
String Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
if (!Directory.Exists("C:\\Users\\Krupal\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\Krupal\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate);
}
```

This code have made directory with current date. 
But when I want to store file in that directory, it generates the error:

> Could not find a part of the path
>   'D:\WORK\RNSB\RNSB\bin\Debug\22-01-2020\22-01-2020.XLS
>    Belove path is store excel file that i have to store.

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Todaysdate+"\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".XLS"))
```

Comment: How is winforms involved?

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually perform the save of the excel file? It suggests you just save it with a file name and not the full path, judging by the fact it is trying to save to the output folder. Also hard-coding a path is bad practice, if anyone else runs your application their user folder is different, use *Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)* instead.

Comment: this is the path that store the fileusing (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Todaysdate+"\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".XLS"))

Comment: Seems like you're not including most of the path

Comment: what i have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are making the directory in a path then you are saving the .xls in another path.

You are making the directory using this path:

```
"C:\\Users\\Krupal\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate
```

Then, here the path where you are trying to save the .xls:

```
Todaysdate+"\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".XLS"
```

The error shows the problem clearly, it could not fin this path:

> D:\WORK\RNSB\RNSB\bin\Debug\22-01-2020\22-01-2020.XLS

While creating the .xls you are omitting the root path, so the process looks for the path `22-01-2020\22-01-2020.XLS` in his working directory `D:\WORK\RNSB\RNSB\bin\Debug`.

You just need to align those paths: I sugget you to use relative paths, so here how you should fix your code:

```
String Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
if (!Directory.Exists(Todaysdate))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(Todaysdate);
}

//then

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Todaysdate+"\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".XLS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are running your `WinForms` application in Debug mode.  This means that your current path is [your application path]\bin\Debug.  If you look in file explorer, you will find that an executable has been created there. When using `StreamWriter` without an absolute file name, the file it tries to create is relative to the current execution path (in your case 'D:\WORK\RNSB\RNSB\bin\Debug').  `StreamWriter` will create a new file, if one does not exist, but it will not create a new folder, and you are passing it Todaysdate + "\\" which is effectively a new folder.  Hence you are getting the error message.

To fix your problem, you need to provide the absolute path to your newly created directory thus:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Krupal\\Desktop\\" + Todaysdate+"\\"+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") +".XLS"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Winforms always expect directories inside Debug Folder, since it's EXE file is inside Debug and try to find it inside Debug folder.
In error it clearly shows that it is looking inside "Debug" folder. 
Can you check whether File Exists in the mentioned folder created by you in C Drive.

// To Write File
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines.txt", lines);
You can follow this MSDN Post, hope it helps, if Yes, please Upvote it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file